# Why does "delete" operator giving me Access violation

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation, delete-operator

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *res=new int[0];

int res_size;

void multiply(int y);

void factorial(int x)

{

    res[0]=1;
    res_size=1;
    for (int i=2;i<=x;i++)
        multiply(i);
    for (int i=res_size-1;i>=0;i--)
        cout << res[i];
}

void multiply(int y)

{

    static int prod=1;
    int carry=0;
    for (int i=0;i<res_size;i++)
    {
        prod=res[i]*y+(carry);
        res[i]=prod%10;
        carry=prod/10;
    }
    while (carry)
    {
        res[res_size]=carry%10;
        carry=carry/10;
        res_size++;
    }
}

int main()

{

    int n;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    factorial(n);
    delete[] res;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am using delete[] operator why I am getting

```
Access violation reading location at address
```

Comment: you allocate space for 0 elements and then access the array out-of-bounds. Are you sure that the problem is the `delete`?

Comment: use `std::vector` if you want to avoid this and many more problems.

Comment: advice: you really shouldnt have res as global, you should pass it as arg to your functions

Comment: Its working fine if I am not using delete operator so allocating space for 0 elements is not a problem as it is dynamically allocated.

Answer (score 3):

You allocated an array with zero elements

```
int *res=new int[0];
```

You may not write to such an array as you are doing

```
res[0]=1;
```

The program has undefined behavior.

Instead of the dynamically allocated array you could use the class template `std::vector`. In this case you could use the method `push_back` to add elements to the vector.

Comment: Note that simply replacing the array with a vector would not fix this code, because the vector would still have to be sized.

Comment: @FredLarson He can use the method push_back to add elements to the vector.